# Different Values for MD5 between Ruby and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby, encoding, cryptography, md5

I need to be able to run an MD5 hash on the same file from a clientside JavaScript app and on a server with Ruby.

Currently I cannot get both hashes to be identical.

On the client, I'm using [JQuery File Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) to upload a file to an S3 bucket. I am using [Crypto](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) to hash the file in a callback:

```
file =  data.files[0]
filename = file.name;
md5 = CryptoJS.MD5(CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(data.files[0].toString()));
```

This gives me: **ee9cd5bf4272fc35bd57d184553bd25b**

In Ruby, it's a module [Digest::MD5](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/digest/1.9.3/Digest/MD5) module that is used by a Gem doing the hashing:

```
Digest::MD5.file(file).to_s
```

This gives me: **4d51c9a4d3fd076489d6c96614ebce61**

**I have no control over the Ruby side of things, but why might the checksum generated by Crypto be different?**

Note that I can test this locally, using the same API:

```
path = 'path/to/file.jpg'
Digest::MD5.file(f).hexdigest
# 4d51c9a4d3fd076489d6c96614ebce61
```

The file is a large jpg (~ 1.8meg)

Update: In response to @kxyz's answer, the results using different encoders for crypto-js are:

```
CryptoJS.MD5(CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(data.files[0].toString()));
// ee9cd5bf4272fc35bd57d184553bd25b

CryptoJS.MD5(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(data.files[0].toString()));
// 709d1d31dc47636e4f5ccbfd07601c19

CryptoJS.MD5(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(data.files[0].toString()));
// 709d1d31dc47636e4f5ccbfd07601c19
```

I've also checked both the orginal file the copied file downloaded from S3 using bash `md5` which generated the same hash for both files:

**4d51c9a4d3fd076489d6c96614ebce61** which is identical to the hash being generated by Ruby.

Also checked the hash using an [online hasher](https://md5file.com/calculator):

**4d51c9a4d3fd076489d6c96614ebce61**

Comment: Are you sure the input is identical in both cases? Perhaps the input is being encoded differently, or perhaps leading or trailing whitespace is being stripped in one case but not the other.

Comment: @Jordan The file is a jpg. I can take both files - original and copy - and run a (ruby) MD5 hash on them and it is identical.

Comment: Could you reduce your example to clean ruby method call (see inside ruby gem how they did it)?

Comment: @aratak I've added the ruby. It's a plain Ruby module.

Answer (score 2):

You use `CryptoJS.enc.Latin1` and in Ruby you don't define encoding `Digest::MD5.file(file).to_s`. Be sure to use the same encoding.

Try

```
Digest::MD5.hexdigest('foobar')
```

and

```
CryptoJS.MD5(CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('foobar'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've switched to using Hex: `CryptoJS.enc.Hex` but this also gives me the wrong hash. I've updated the question.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to parse "foobar" from hex because it isn't hex. You probably mean `CryptoJS.MD5('foobar').toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);`

Answer (score 1):

`data.files[0].toString()` is not doing what you think it's doing. It just returns an "[object File]" string and not the contents of the file.

You actually need to read the file for example like this:

```js
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function(e) {
    var contents = e.target.result;
    var hash = CryptoJS.MD5(contents);

    console.log(hash);
    console.log(hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));
};

// Read in the image file as a data URL.
reader.readAsBinaryString(data.files[0]);
```

The output of `CryptoJS.MD5()` is the native CryptoJS binary array (`WordArray`). When printed as string it is serialized to Hex encoding by default. If you want another encoding, then you need to pass it into it's `toString()` function.

Comment: Thanks. But the hashes are all the same, whether using `CryptoJS.enc.Base64` or one of the others.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem on a web host using [uWSGI](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Turns out the uploaded file data was off by a few characters, which caused md5 to not match, and Rails to issue a 422 response after deleting the uploaded file.

Here is the fix if you find yourself in the same situation:

```rb
# app/controllers/upload_controller.rb <- Create this file
class UploadController < ActiveStorage::DiskController
  def update
    request.env['RAW_POST_DATA'] = request.body.read(request.content_length)
    super
  end
end

# config/routes.rb <- Edit this file
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # [your routes]

  # Add the following two lines:
  # Fix IntegrityError caused by uWSGI upload
  put '/rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_token', to: 'upload#update'
end
```

[Original discussion (in French)](https://forum.alwaysdata.com/viewtopic.php?pid=21242#p21242) where the fix was found.